# Appium Inspector: Call to 'tap' failed

Tags: android-testing, tap, appium-inspector

I am having a problem with this program. When I select a button it throws me that error and I can't continue. Anyone know what might be happening?
You can see the problem here[Image of the tap error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88yIY.png)
Different texts have been deleted from the image for security, but the element has id.

I´m trying to realize a test of a flow